# PIN number forgotten, phone is locked

Tags: locked-out

Note 3 was accidentally locked, PIN number forgotten, tried using Google account to retrieve photos saved on phone, but Location is not enabled on the device and phone cannot be located. Only 2 attempts left before it does a factory reset and wipes out all my photos. Saving photos is my priority. Any suggestions for accessing device as described above? Thank you.

Comment: When it goes into the locked state, wifi is automatically switched on, so try creating an unprotected hotspot, from another device, and login from google, it should work...just make sure you are sure about your password....ive been locked out of my samsung tab S, and the same worked out...so hopefully this helps